# CSS webkit height

Tags: css, webkit

i have an problem with a div box, which has to get a specific height: 241px.
In all  browser it is displayed right, but in chrome and safari it dis only 230px height

Is there a possiblility, per example with a css hack to modify this box only in webkit browsers?

Comment: Do you have a jsfiddle for this? I'm sure this only happends in certain circumstances, so it's hard for us to just reproduce this.

Comment: @w00: It's best to link to it. http://jsfiddle.net/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's possible to apply CSS rules only on webkit-based browsers by placing them in a media query referencing a webkit specific property:

```
@media screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:0) {
    /* webkit specific CSS */
    div#mydiv { height:241px; }
}
```

Comment: I wish you hadn't posted this. If he goes ahead and uses this, he'll never find out what the actual problem was.

Comment: I think you are right thirtydot, but i need a fast fix at this moment. Thx John Lawrence

Answer (score 0):

I am curious if your problem stemmed from a box-sizing setting.

It could have been so I provide this answer for that reason, and because thirtydot pointed out the accepted answer doesn't help you understand why you have this problem.

For me, chrome would not display box-sizing: padding-box so I had to use border-box which mostly worked except that elements that are lined up next to it are not getting rendered the same if I depend on height. This is because the ultimate height in mozilla using a padding-box will be two pixels short of the element in chrome set to border-box.

The Solution there is to make the elements consistent. So I need to take my other element (the one I want to line up) and make it use border-box and padding-box respectively. I could try to tell it to have different heights depending on browser by using your answer, but I think that isn't the best idea.

```
-webkit-box-sizing: padding-box;
-moz-box-sizing: padding-box;
box-sizing: border-box;
```