# Gap between two <div> vertically aligned

Tags: html, css

I have a display problem with every browser except Firefox.
I actually have this type of code

```html
<div id="conteneur">
  <div id="milieu">
    <div class="textPara">
      <div id="conteneur">
        <div id="cadre_selection_ecole">
          <form id="form_search">
            <input type="text" value="" />
            <script type="text/javascript">
              disableAutocomplete('search');
            </script>
            <div id="listerecherche" style="margin-top:-15px; text-align:left"></div>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="footer">
  SOME TEXT
</div>
```

The fact is that there is a gap created between "div **id="milieu"**" and "div **id="footer"**".
I already tried solutions that involve to add to css some browser webkits, font size and so on.
When I use the code inspector, it shows me that this gap is nothing but a no-code zone.

You will find here [the gap between the two divs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jk8F8.png).

Any suggestion ?

Comment: Can you please create codepen so that I can inspect?

Comment: As the website is composed by images that can't be accessed, I can't create properly a codepen. Without these images, you won't see the gap. Sorry, I know that it won't be easy to help me in these conditions

Comment: please add a working exemple

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested by RompePC (thanks), i tried the top rated solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11012129/css-webkit-height).
I adapted it to my problem like that

```css
@media screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:0) {
    /* webkit specific CSS */
    div#milieu { height:0px; }
    div#footer { height:0px; }
}
```

My problem is now solved.

Comment: Great, so it was an issue of webkit based browsers. I apologize didn't fall into it earlier (disabling a property is only available at the web tools, and setting it to `auto` wouldn't work because is a specific rendering web motor issue).

Comment: As you led to the solution, you really don't have to apologize!

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that `<form>` has a height stablished by default (at least in Chrome, which is 39px). Eliminating this property should do the work (maybe you have to do extra work, as setting a `<p>SOME TEXT</p>` instead of pure text).

Comment: Tried to set this height to auto size (with jquery and css), but it didn't change anything :/

Comment: I not mean setting to auto, I mean **not setting/disabling it**.

Comment: Seems I can't find any information on disabling a default height of a form, are you sure of your answer ?

Comment: When I get home from work I'll give you a full working example. In the meantime, try [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11012129/css-webkit-height), maybe it'll work, sorry :(